# Invalid initialization of non-const reference with C++11 thread?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm getting an error about

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’

from

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func(int& i){
    cout<<++i<<endl;
}

int main(){
    int x=7;
    thread t(func,x);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that I can't do `thread(func, 4)` but `x` is a variable, not a temporary.

I am using gcc 4.7 with -std=c++11 -pthread

Why is this error occurring?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the implementation.

Comment: @bames53, this behaviour is required by the standard.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Ah, I see. I took a quick look at the definition of `std::thread` and saw the perfect forwarding but I didn't stop to remember/consider the significance of `DECAY_COPY`.

Comment: You can pass a pointer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The specification for the `std::thread` constructor says

> *Effects:* Constructs an object of type thread. The new thread of execution executes *INVOKE* `(` *DECAY_COPY* `( std::forward<F>(f)),` *DECAY_COPY* `(std::forward<Args>(args))...)` with the calls to *DECAY_COPY* being evaluated in the constructing thread.

Where *DECAY_COPY(x)* means calling `decay_copy(x)` where that is defined as:

```
template <class T> typename decay<T>::type decay_copy(T&& v)
{ return std::forward<T>(v); }
```

What this means is that the arguments "decay" and are copied, meaning that they are forwarded *by value* and lose any cv-qualification.  Because the target function run by the thread wants to take its parameter *by reference*, you get a compiler error saying the reference cannot bind to an object passed by value.

This is by design, so that by default local variables passed to a `std::thread` get passed by value (i.e. copied) not by reference, so that the new thread will not have dangling references to local variables that go out of scope, leading to undefined behaviour.

If you know it's safe to pass the variables by reference then you need to do so explicitly, using a `reference_wrapper` which will not be affected by the "decay" semantics, and will forward the variable by reference to the target object. You can create a `reference_wrapper` using `std::ref`.

Comment: I really really wonder why the standard didn't give us `std::invoke` and `std::decay_copy`...

Comment: Thank you! I had never heard of decay_copy before.

Comment: @AlexanderDuchene, `decay_copy` is not a real function, it's just used in the standard to explain the semantics. You won't find it in the standard library.

Comment: I came across this as well and I want to add that if the target function's argument is const int& or int&&, it will work. So I think the reason non-const ref does not work is because a rvalue is passed to it.

Comment: @szli, yes, that's exactly what the compiler error says! _"from an rvalue of type ‘int’"_. The thing to understand is that the target function gets passed a _copy_ of the argument _as an rvalue_.

Answer (score 16):

Wrap `x` in `std::ref` when you create the thread.

If every time you created a `std::thread` it took all variables by reference, think what would happen: if you passed a stack-local variable in, it would be a dangling reference, and undefined behavior would result if the thread outlived the scope of that automatic storage variable.  This would happen a lot in practice, and result in many bugs.  Instead, `std::thread` by default takes (marshals via perfect forwarding) all arguments (including variables) by value.

The `std::future` could silently work when calling your worker function by passing in a thread-local lvalue copy of `x`, but that would be pretty confusing: the worker task would edit `x` that you thought you passed by reference, and it wouldn't show up in the `x` outside of the task.  Instead, it helpfully gives you that error message.  You should be thanking your lucky stars for it!

In order to indicate that you really really want to not take something by value, you wrap it in `std::ref`, and now it is passed all the way to the worker function as a reference.  In this case, you are responsible for managing the lifetime of the reference so that the data referred to lasts at least as long as the `std::future`'s worker task needs it.

Comment: That would fix the error, but the question asks why it is an error.

Comment: @juanchopanza true -- I was on my phone, so I typed out a quick fix to Alex's problem.  Details now added.